# How to estimate parameters of a nonlinear polynomial model by using Maximum Likelihood Estimation?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, box-jenkins

Assume that you are having an equation that looks like this. It's a Box-Jenkins model.

$$F(q)D(q)y[k] = B(q)D(q)u[k] + F(q)C(q)e[k]$$

Where $F(q), D(q), B(q), C(q)$ are polynomials such as:

$$B(q) = 1 + b_1q^{-1} + \dots + b_nq^{-n}$$
$$F(q) = 1 + f_1q^{-1} + \dots + f_nq^{-m}$$
$$C(q) = 1 + c_1q^{-1} + \dots + c_nq^{-i}$$
$$D(q) = 1 + d_1q^{-1} + \dots + d_nq^{-j}$$

These e.g $b_nq^{-n}$ are the same as $b_n(k-n)$. It's just a way to say shift.

$e(k) = y(k) - \hat y(k)$ is the accuracy error and can be computed recursively. These types of equations as you see above, requires Maximum Likeliehood Estimation (MLE) to find each parameters.

**Question:**

Assume that you are having this equation where $m = 2, n = 2, i = 3, j = 3$. Only $u(k)$ and $y(k)$ are known.

$$[y(k)+f_1y(k-1) + f_2y(k-2)][y(k)+d_1y(k-1) + d_2y(k-2) + d_3y(k-3)] = [u(k)+b_1u(k-1) + b_2u(k-2)][u(k)+d_1u(k-1) + d_2u(k-2) + d_3u(k-3)] + [e(k)+f_1e(k-1) + f_2e(k-2)][e(k)+c_1e(k-1) + c_2e(k-2) + c_3e(k-3)]$$

If I'm going to use Maximum Likelihood Estimation for finding each parameters. How should I do then?

Comment: By "How should I do [it]?", are you asking for suggestions of which numerical algo to use?

Comment: @JohnMadden Yes. Where do I begin? I know that MLE is the right tool, or is there a better tool to use? I have been watching at youtube and it describes MLE very well, but not MLE in polynomial curve fitting.

Comment: ah gotcha, I don't know about this problem in particular, but in general multivariate polynomial minimization is not much easier than general nonlinear minimization, so I would start with general purpose first order methods like BFGS. In R, this is available using the optim function and the parameter "method='BFGS'" (for large systems you would probably want to compute the gradient by hand and provide it to the function, but to get started you can leave this blank and it will do numerical differentiation). Do you have a preferred computing environment?

Comment: @JohnMadden I prefer GNU Octave. It's a MATLAB clone. I don't know R. Gone one course in it, but not learn anything. I have a nonlinear kalman filter algorithm for parameter estimation, but not sure if MLE is better han kalman filter parameter estimation. Give it a try you.

Comment: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid/blob/master/reports/SR-UKF.pdf Here is the Kalman filter parameter estimation algorithm.

Comment: not a MATLAB expert, but as far as I know the standard function for multivariate nonlinear optimization in MATLAB is fminsearch [though looking at the docs, this is derivative free, so it may struggle in high D parameter spaces]

Comment: @JohnMadden Yes. I have been using fminsearch a lot for parameter estimation. It works. But do you think it will work for this problem above? =) Thank you.

Comment: @JohnMadden To make that work, fminsearch, I need to know the model error $e(k)$ as well. So there fore, I need some kind of recursive method. I wonder If I could assume that $e(0)  = 1$  to begin with, then compute $e(1)$ after I have called fminsearch?

Comment: Fminsearch give the same result as kalman filter parameter estimation. But I think fminsearch is using gradient descent.

Comment: " I wonder If I could assume that e(0)=1 to begin with, then compute e(1) after I have called fminsearch?" sounds like that might be worth a shot!

Comment: @JohnMadden Yes. I think I will do that. I just heard from my professor that MLE is the preffered choice for box-jenkins modelling, but I did not get any explonation why.

Comment: @JohnMadden I opend a new question about that. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602076/recursive-maximum-likelihood-estimation-algorithm-the-same-as-maximum-likeliho