# Recursive Maximum Likelihood Estimation algorithm - The same as Maximum Likelihood Estimation?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, estimation, box-jenkins, recursive-model

I have the book "Adaptive Control", Second edition, from Karl-Johan Åström and at page 61 to 62 he wrote:

**Stochastic models**

The least-squares estimate is biased when it used on data generated by Eq. (2.12) where the errors $e(i)$ are correlated. The reason is that the $E\phi^T(i)e(i) \neq 0$ (compare Eq. (2.13)). A possibility to cope with this problem is to model the correlation of the disturbances and to estimated the parameters describing the correlations. Consider the model (2.38)

$$A(q)y(t) = B(q)u(t) + C(q)e(t)$$

where $A(q), B(q), $ and $C(q)$ are polynomials in the forward shift operator and ${e(t)}$ is the white noise. The parameters of the polynomial $C$ describe the correlation of the disturbance. The model of Eq. (2.38) cannot be converted directly to a regression mode, since the variables ${e(t)}$ are not known. A regression model can, however, be obtained by suitable approximations. To desrcibe these, introduce

$$\epsilon(t) = y(t) - \phi^T(t-1)\hat \theta(t-1)$$

where

$$\theta = (a_1 \dots a_n \space b_1 \dots b_n \space c_1 \dots c_n)$$
$$\phi^T(t-1) = (-y(t-1) \dots -y(t-n) \space u(t-1) \dots u(t-n) \space \epsilon(t-1) \dots  \epsilon(t-n))$$

The variables $e(t)$ are approximated by the prediction errors $\epsilon(t)$. The model can then be appriximated by

$$y(t) = \phi^T(t-1)\theta + e(t)$$

and standard recursive least squares can be applied. The method obtained is called *extended least squares (ELS)*. The equations for updating the estimates are givien by (2.39)

$$\hat \theta(t) = \hat \theta(t-1) + P(t)\phi(t-1)\epsilon(t)$$
$$P^{-1}(t) = P^{-1}(t-1) + \phi(t-1)\phi^T(t-1)$$

(Compare with Theorem 2.3.) Another method for estimating the parameters in Eq. (2.38) is to use Eqs. (2.39) and let the residual be defined by (2.40)

$$\hat C(q) \epsilon(t) = \hat A(q)y(y) - \hat B(q)u(t)$$

and regression vector $\phi$ in Eqs. (2.39) be replaced by $\phi_f$, where (2.41)

$$\hat C(q)\phi_f(t) = \phi(t)$$

The most recent estimates should be used in these updates. The method obtained is then not truly recursive, since Eqs. (2.41) and (2.40) have to be solved from $t = 1$ for each measurement. The following approximation can be made

$$\epsilon(t) = y(t) - \phi_f^T(t-1)\hat \theta(t-1)$$

This algorithm is called the *recursive maximum likelihood (RML)* method. It is adventageous for both ELS and RML to replace the residual in the regression vector by the posterior residual defined as

$$\epsilon_p(t) = y(t) - \phi^T(t-1)\hat \theta(t)$$

that is, the least value of $\hat \theta$ is used to compute $\epsilon_p$.

Another possibility to model the correlated noise is to use the model

$$y(t) = \frac{B(q)}{A(q)}u(t) + \frac{C(q)}{D(q)}e(t)$$

instead of Eq. (2.38). Recursive parameter estimation for this model can be derived in the same was as for Eq. (2.38).

---

Now I'm writing.
To summerize what he wrote. If you got $u(t), y(t)$ and you want to find a dynamical model. You could use

$$A(q)y(t) = B(q)u(t) + C(q)e(t)$$

or

$$y(t) = \frac{B(q)}{A(q)}u(t) + \frac{C(q)}{D(q)}e(t)$$

All you need to do is to create a regression vector that fits your model e.g

$$\theta = (a_1 \dots a_n \space b_1 \dots b_n \space c_1 \dots c_n)$$

or

$$\theta = (a_1 \dots a_n \space b_1 \dots b_n \space c_1 \dots c_n \space d_1 \dots d_n)$$

together with

$$\phi^T(t-1) = (-y(t-1) \dots -y(t-n) \space u(t-1) \dots u(t-n) \space \epsilon(t-1) \dots  \epsilon(t-n))$$

Then you are looping the algorithm:

$$\hat \theta(t) = \hat \theta(t-1) + P(t)\phi_f(t-1)\epsilon_p(t)$$
$$P^{-1}(t) = P^{-1}(t-1) + \phi_f(t-1)\phi_f^T(t-1)$$
$$\epsilon_p(t) = y(t) - \phi_f^T(t-1)\hat \theta(t)$$

Where

$$\phi_f(t) = \frac{1}{\hat C(q)}\phi(t)$$

A good choise of $P(0)$ is to have it diagonal with large numbers $P = cI$ where $c$ is a large number.

**Question:**

When I watch videos at youtube about *Maximum Likelihood Estimation*, they are using other equations. I don't recognize these equation when it comes to *Maximum Likelihood Estimation*. I know that this algorithm is recursive, but I cannot see any distribution equation or mean, standard deviation etc here.

It seems that this algorithm is some kind of modification of *Recursive Least Squares*. I have tried RLS and it works very good for models such as.

$$A(q)y(t) = B(q)u(t) + C(q)e(t)$$

But it does not work for Box-Jenkins models such as, which the author of the book says that *Recursive Maximum Likelihood Estimation* is a good choice for this Box-Jenkins model

$$y(t) = \frac{B(q)}{A(q)}u(t) + \frac{C(q)}{D(q)}e(t)$$

So to my question, can anyone prove that this is actually the same as *Maximum Likelihood Estimation*, despite that this algorithm above is **recursive**?

An ready-to-use RLS algorithm can be found at [MataveID](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid/blob/master/sourcecode/rls.m). Exampels can be found in the [example folder](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid/blob/master/examples/rlsExample.m).

Comment: Hi: The usage " recursive MLE" is because it's being discussed in the context of the Kalman filter which is recursive by definition. So, the MLE is used at each update step of the Kalman filter. They call it recursive because it's updated from time $t$ to time $t+1$ for all $t$. If you are not familiar with the kalman filter recursions there are many discussions on the internet. If you need a  specific reference, there is one that I'm thinking of that I'll try to find and send the link.

Comment: I can't say this is the best one because there are so many discussions but hopefully you will find it useful. https://people.math.umass.edu/~lavine/courses/797/kalman_filter.pdf

Comment: @mlofton So you mean that this RLE is a kalman filter and has no relation to regular Maximum Likelihood Estimation method?

Comment: @mlofton By the way. Do you know how to interpret $\frac{1}{\hat C(q)}$ ?

Comment: @mlofton Or does it mean that $\frac{1}{\hat C(q)}$ is a filter? Like a transfer function?

Comment: Hi euradd: Yes,  recursive least squares, as I know it, is a special case of the kalman filter where there is no system equation. ( KF usually consists of two equations, the observation and the system equation ). I'm not familar with the notation Astrom is using in the RLS case but I bet the Astrom book has references in the back for the basic KF.  I don't have time right now to try to back out$\hat{C(q)}$ and, even if I did have the time, I might not be able to. I have that Astrom book somewhere so, I'll try to find it and on my travellngs today, take a look. But I can't guarantee success.

Comment: Note that, I'm pretty sure that if you match the notation with that of the standard KF, it's possible to figure out where those expressions are coming from.

Comment: I didn't look at it carefully because I'm in a rush but here is a link that might be helpful ? https://lukemerrick.com/posts/recursive_least_squares.html

Comment: @euradd: I found my book but it's by astrom and wittenmark and second edition. hopefully it's not so different from the one you are looking at. I'll check it out but don't get your hopes up. control is not an area that I know much about.

Comment: @mlofton the text above is from the second edition. It would be interesting to know how myck RML differ from regular Maximum Likelihood

Comment: I glanced at the book today and could see how what you wrote comes from there. The two methods that are relevant seem to be extended least squares and recursive maximum likelihood ( see bottom of page 62 right before Unification section ). The author says that relevant references are in the back of the chapter but I was not able to tell what the relevant references were. My best guess is that the rwo relevant references are the two under "Recursive identification and properties of recursive estimators are treated in depth in" on page 87.

Comment: As far as the difference between recursive maximum likelihood and maximum likelihood, they are pretty different animals so I wouldn't really worry about relating them. maximum likelihood is a method uses to generate a maximum likelihood estimate by maximizing the likelihood of the density numerically. In recursive MLE, one is obtaining the maxumum likeihood estimate of the MODEL at each time step $t$ so it's kind of like MLE but it's being done over and over again at each new time $t$. I think you will understand recursive MLE more clearly if you first get familiar with the kalman filter.

Comment: Personally, I'm not pleased with the way the book proceeds because, to me, first the KF should be covered in the general case. Then, in a subsequent chapter, these variiations on the KF such as extended least squares and whatever other methods he discusses should be covered. He's covering variations of the KF in a very succinct manner and he never even really covers the general case which is the KF itself. Maybe you want to look at Anderson and Moore to get a decent handle on the KF. Then, after that, chapter 2 won't be as confusing because  those variations are just special cases of the KF.

Comment: Anderson and Moore also have a book on optimal control that I've never looked at but it may do a better job than Astrom and Wittenmark are far as coverage of these other recursive methods. I don't know that for sure but it's a possibility.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Optimal-Filtering-Dover-Electrical-Engineering/dp/0486439380/ref=sr_1_2?crid=1A5I1QS5DA6Z7&keywords=anderson+and+moore+kalman+filter&qid=1674102744&sprefix=anderson+and+moore+kalman+filter%2Caps%2C87&sr=8-2

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Optimal-Control-Quadratic-Methods-Engineering/dp/0486457664/ref=sr_1_1?crid=CI65S33VSUSZ&keywords=anderson+and+moore+optimal+control&qid=1674102789&sprefix=anderson+and+moore+optimal+control%2Caps%2C103&sr=8-1

Comment: I can vouch for the first book but not the second ( I do have the second but, as I said, optimal control is not my field ).

Comment: @mlofton So what you are saying is that RML has no relation to ML. OK, that explains everything. I tried this RML and I got it to work, sort of. Not finished yet. I notise that I was using `rls.m` and modify it with $\hat C(q)$ polynomial. This example above is `Extended Least Squares` that are modified to `RML`. Also I notice that $\hat C(q)$ is just a way to filter $\phi$.

Comment: Hi Euraad: Yes, there's no important connection. MLE is more general. Recursive MLE is specifically for when you have a regression model ( or a variant of a regression model ) that you want to re-estimate the parameters of , each time a new data point comes in at each new time step "t". The reason they call it recursive MLE rather than say recursive regression modelling is because, at each step, one uses the MLE procedure ( or some variant of an MLE ) to estimate the parameters of that model at that time step. But they really are not related other than that.

Comment: As I said, I would get a handle on the KF before you deal with recursive regression models because the latter are all special cases of the KF. Anderson and Moore at one time was the bible for the KF. I don't know if it still is but it's a good book.

Comment: @mlofton I tried Mr. Åström's RML and it seems that it was not perfect. It did not work. But when I look at his equations, I understand that this RML is just least squares, but recursive. I found this paper and I think this is a simple solution to this paper. This paper introduces two methods. What do you think? https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1049/iet-spr.2012.0183

Comment: @mlofton I looked up Anderson and Moore's book and I think KF filter was very heavy explained and was suited for researchers. I have a book about regular KF with ARE-equations and that book explains KF very simple, but still solve the problem . In my opinion, I think all the control theory, system identification, filtering etc. lacks when it comes to problem solving.

Comment: @mlofton By the way! Box-Jenkis is a 2 model system, one system model and one disturbance model. Can't I just identifiy the system model, then compute the error $e(t)$ from real measurement minus system model minus? Then use $e(t)$ and compute the disturbance model?

Comment: I am printing out the paper and will try to read it during the week. Anderson and Moore is an excellent book. I don't think you need to read the whole thing but I would read the chapter or chapters that introduce and explain the KF.

Comment: I guess one can think of box-jenkins as a 2 model system but it's all sandwiched into one model through the use of the ARMA formulation. There are algorithms ( I think the original paper might be by Kohn and Ansley. Something like "estimating the parametes of an autoregressive moving average model". ) for estimating the parameters of an ARMA model so I'm not clear on what the paper you referred to does but I'll take a look.

Comment: @mlofton I have successfully computed the Box-Jenkins model, by using subspace identification. I talked to a professor and he said that the best way to compute box-jenkins is using subspace methods. It was quite easy to implement, but the math was difficult. So now I have my disturbance model $\frac{C(q)}{D(q)}$ with the disturbance $e(t)$ which is a gaussian disturbance.

Comment: @mlofton Are you familiar with MATLAB/Octave? If so, I have a library at my GitHub you might like. Me and one from John Deere are building on it. Make system identification pratical and not theoretical. It's challenging. I have a whole laboratory/workshop where I can use these tools whenever I want.

Comment: I don't have so much time these days but, if you send me the link, it's appreciated. I'll try to take a look at some point. My experience is mostly with R.

Comment: @mlofton https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid i have been using R back in the days, but the MATLAB language got me instead due to matrix algebra.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to take a look at some point. Note that R has Rcpp which include RArmadillo so lots of fancy matrix algebra is available.